# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in MvxTableViewSource.GetItemAt

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a custom TableViewSource which inherits from MvxSimpleTableViewSource:

```
public class MyTableViewSource : MvxSimpleTableViewSource
{
    private readonly MyViewModel viewModel;

    public MyTableViewSource(MyViewModel viewModel, UITableView tableView)
        : base(tableView, MyTeaserCell.Key, MyTeaserCell.Key)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return this.viewModel.Items.Count; 
    }
}
```

Sometimes GetItemAt, which is not overriden by me, throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

The stacktrace is:

```
Parameter name: index', reason: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
 at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () <0x2bef74 +     0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (Int32 index) <0x19f620 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].System.Collections.IList.get_Item (Int32 index) <0x1a6ff4 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxEnumerableExtensions.ElementAt (IEnumerable items, Int32 position) <0x8fceac + 0x00103> in <filename unknown>:0 
at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Views.MvxTableViewSource.GetItemAt (Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) <0x958830 + 0x00053> in <filename unknown>:0 
at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Views.MvxBaseTableViewSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) <0x957940 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) <0x834b50 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x834a78 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
at App.Application.Main (System.String[] args) <0xc66cc + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 '
```

At the moment I can not clearly reproduce this exception, but it happens 2 to 3 times a day.
It seems to me that GetItemAt sometimes is called before the ItemsSource has items.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need custom class `MyTableViewSource`, just use `MvxSimpleTableViewSource` directly

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (tableView, MyTeaserCell.Key, MyTeaserCell.Key);

//apply binding
set.Bind(source).To(vm=>vm.Items);
```

**Another way** inside MyTableViewSource, just need to **remove** `RowsInSection`. It's implemented already with `ItemsSource.Count`

Comment: I used a custom class, because I know that I need to implement some other features like editing and so on. But the advice to remove `RowsInSection` sounds good. I will give it a try...